# Iphone4 "add to home screen" instant startup

Tags: iphone, performance, html

How do you make a web app start up instantly - is it possible to make as fast as a native app that is already loaded?

I have developed a HTML5 web app that runs nicely on Iphone 4 with a splashscreen. But now I'm looking into performance:

I use a manifest file to ensure that all files are loaded from the local storage. I have checked both in chrome and mobile safari, that the files are stored correctly locally. Now performance it quite different depending on how I access my web app:

~4s When I load the web app in browser (not from a home screen icon).
~6s When I load from an "add to homescreen" icon

When I load in chrome browser it takes 234ms to load and render the whole page. I seems like the lack of speed is due to the rendering being pretty slow.

Any performance suggestions are very welcome.

Comment: One suggestion - load and display the activity indicator with the most simple UI first instead of the complete app.

Answer (score 0):

I know from experience that a MacOSX device the Chrome App all of its previous versions/updates leaves in its App. This maybe also apply to ios, since it's is a stripped version of the MacOSX sysem.

It might help to delete the Chrome App from your iPhone and re-install it from the App store. 
This way you be sure you have a clean copy op Chrome on the iPhone whithout all the previous Chrome versions.

I hope this helps.